# Dirichlet for panel data: correlated random effects?

Tags: panel-data, compositional-data, dirichlet-regression

I was wondering whether I can apply a Dirichlet regression model to panel data (using either `dirifit` in Stata or `DirichReg` in R)? I would do this by adding time averages of the time-invariant variables (Mundlak device) to obtain a Correlated Random Effects model. I have done this before for tobit and probit models, but I am not certain whether the same procedure applies to Dirichlet models.

If not, are there any other compositional data models applicable to panel data?

Thank you.

Comment: Hi, you can transform your dirichlet data by for example alr transformation and use normal regression.

Comment: @pikachu, ok! This is a valuable suggestion, thank you.