# Are there any compositional data models applicable to panel data?

Tags: panel-data, compositional-data

I have a dataset spread across N departments and T years. I am interested in how voting shares change as a reaction to some regressor X. The dependent variable Y is vote shares: every department casts votes of which some go to party A, some to party B, and some to party C. Thus, it would be a compositional variable, summing up to 1 in every N.

I have seen a similar analysis being conducted (https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC9041641/) but only for one particular year. Are there any compositional data methods that would allow for a similar analysis across years, accommodating panel data?

The simplest way to go about this would be to perform ILR transformation and continue with a fixed effects model, but is it appropriate from an econometrics perspective?

My question is related to [Dirichlet for panel data: correlated random effects?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/602952/dirichlet-for-panel-data-correlated-random-effects) but it is not answered, unfortunately.